# Monodroid emulator LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation() returns null

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I need to use geolocation to Android (using Monodroid). And I'm left with two problems.

- The first: Should I explicitly warn the user (based on GPS-coordinate
  (as in windows phone)
- The second (more complicated): I followed this    [Localisation
  sample](https://github.com/gshackles/Sample-Projects/blob/master/MonoDroid/MonoDroidSamples/MonoDroidSamples/DemoActivities/LocationDemo/LocationActivity.cs) but still has no lastKnownLocation. Is it    because of
  the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking in the first part of the question. Should you warn the user about what, your use of their location? I'd say that depends on how heavily you're using it, but at the very least they would see that you're requesting the location permission(s) when installing your app.

For the second question, take a look at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10471314/170333) from a few days ago. In short, `GetLastKnownLocation()` can return null if the provider has never received any location updates.

**Edit:**

To answer your question in the comments, there are several ways to mock location data in the emulator. [This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#MockData) in the Android documentation walks through how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
To the first question, I understand that the user is informed conernant GPS when downloading the application (unlike windows phone).
For the second, I stay in the fog, how value can it be updated on the emulator?

Comment: @David I added a note to the question with info on how to mock location data, since it might be useful to someone finding this question in the future and didn't want it buried in comments.

Comment: Thank you! I did not understand but it was very simple.